# Object inheritance with a knockout property

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the following js inheritance example:

```
function Fruit(){
  this.who = function(){ console.dir(this.fruitName); }
}
Fruit.prototype.fruitName = "I am a fruit";

function Orange(){
  Fruit.call();
  this.fruitName = "I am an orange";
}
Orange.prototype = new Fruit();
Orange.prototype.constructor = Orange;

function Apple(){
  Fruit.call();
  this.fruitName = "I am an apple";
}
Apple.prototype = new Fruit();
Apple.prototype.constructor = Orange;

var orange = new Orange();
var apple = new Apple();
orange.who();
apple.who();
```

The code above outputs:

```
I am an orange
I am an apple
```

Which is correct.

Now, changing the `fruitName` to a knockout observable gives an unexpected result:

```
function Fruit(){
  this.who = function(){ console.dir(this.fruitName()); }
}
Fruit.prototype.fruitName = ko.observable("I am a fruit");

function Orange(){
  Fruit.call();
  this.fruitName("I am an orange");
}
Orange.prototype = new Fruit();
Orange.prototype.constructor = Orange;

function Apple(){
  Fruit.call();
  this.fruitName("I am an apple");
}
Apple.prototype = new Fruit();
Apple.prototype.constructor = Orange;

var orange = new Orange();
var apple = new Apple();
orange.who();
apple.who();
```

Output:

```
I am an apple
I am an apple
```

Unless I am doing something wrong, this looks like a bug in Knockout.
Is there a way around this issue?

Full jsfiddle available here: https://jsfiddle.net/h1go9se2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What's going on

The idea of the prototype is that it's shared between instances. Functions use `this` to make sure running the methods actually impacts a single instance.

Knockout observables are functions, but they're best thought of as wrappers around a value.

If you define your observable on the prototype, it means you're wrapping a value to be shared by all instances.

Writing to that value in the constructor of any class that extends it will overwrite the value for all instances.

### The fix

Instead of declaring `fruitName` on the `Fruit` prototype, you define the property inside the `Fruit` constructor:

```js
function Fruit(){
  this.who = function(){ console.dir(this.fruitName()); }
  this.fruitName = ko.observable("I am a fruit");
}
```

Runnable snippet:

```js
function Fruit(){
  this.who = function(){ console.dir(this.fruitName()); }
  this.fruitName = ko.observable("I am a fruit");
}

function Orange(){
  Fruit.call();
  this.fruitName("I am an orange");
}
Orange.prototype = new Fruit();
Orange.prototype.constructor = Orange;

function Apple(){
  Fruit.call();
  this.fruitName("I am an apple");
}
Apple.prototype = new Fruit();
Apple.prototype.constructor = Orange;

var orange = new Orange();
var apple = new Apple();
orange.who();
apple.who();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ah I see. So it is the fact that `ko.observable()` being a function that made the runtime share the same observable across different instances. Thank you for the insights.

Comment: Tried to implement your suggestion within my codebase but I can't get it to work. I posted a new question as I added a bit more context (the issue seems to happen when combining requirejs and knockout): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69994355/inheritance-issue-with-requirejs-and-knockout