# Inheritance issue with RequireJs and Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs

I have a requirejs module that I use as a factory to create objects of different types, the factory is illustrated below:

```
requirejs.config({
    appDir: ".",
    baseUrl: "js",
    paths: { 
        'jquery': '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min',
        'knockout': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.5.1/knockout-latest.min'
    },
     'knockout': { deps: ['jquery'],exports: 'knockout' }
});

define("FruitFactory", ["knockout"], function(ko){
  function Fruit(){
    this.who = function(){ console.dir(this.fruitType()); }
    this.fruitType = ko.observable();
  }
  function Apple(t){
    Fruit.call();
    this.fruitType(t);
  }
  Apple.prototype = new Fruit();
  Apple.prototype.constructor = Apple;
  function createApple(t){
    return new Apple(t);
  }
  return {  createApple: createApple }
});

require(["FruitFactory"], function(factory) {
    var golden = factory.createApple("Golden Delicious");
    var honey = factory.createApple("Honeycrisp");
    golden.who();
    honey.who();    
    return {};
});
```

Output:

```
Honeycrisp
Honeycrisp
```

Why is `golden.who()` yielding `Honeycrisp` instead of `Golden Delicious`?

Full jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/t2xsr7uz/7/

Comment: I am not an expert, but, it looks like that the second call overwrites the first one. This might be caused by javascript prototyping, as it does not have a classic inheritance as other object-oriented languages...

Comment: That's what I thought at first - it isn't the case (ref. another question I asked before this one  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69984364/object-inheritance-with-a-knockout-property/69985466#69985466 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can fix it by explicitly passing `this` to the `Fruit.call` method in your `Apple` constructor:

```js
function Fruit() {
  this.who = function() {
    console.dir(this.fruitType());
  }
  this.fruitType = ko.observable();
}

function Apple(t) {
  Fruit.call(this);
  this.fruitType(t);
}
Apple.prototype = new Fruit();
Apple.prototype.constructor = Apple;

function createApple(t) {
  return new Apple(t);
}

var golden = createApple("Golden Delicious");
var honey = createApple("Honeycrisp");
golden.who();
honey.who();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! Do you know why this is happening? I couldn't get much insights debugging the code.

Comment: I think that not passing an explicit `this` to `call` either makes `this` refer to `window` or `undefined` or `null` (based on whether you're in strict mode). There's some background info [documented on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call#parameters) A good way to debug it is to put a breakpoint in the constructors of Fruit and Apple and check what `this` refers to in the console.

Comment: Interesting, adding a `console.dir(this)` in the `Fruit()` constructor outputs: `Fruit, Window and Window` the runtime seems to create 3 objects instances instead of just 2 :-o